# Build a vocabulary of distinct words from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, series

I have a Series with index named "Article Number" and a column named "Text". Series looks like this:

```
Article ID   |   Text
  Article#1     This is a beautiful day
  Article#2     I love you
  Article#3     This is too late
  Article#4     Love you back
  Article#5     This is a lovely day

distinct_words = ['This', 'beautiful', 'day']
```

I'd like to create a dictionary which its key is the distinct word and its value is list of article it was in.
so for example above it would be:

```
vocabulary = {"This":[Article#1, Article#3], "beautiful":[Article#1], "day":[Article#1, Article#5}
```

what i have written is:

```
vocabulary ={}
for word in distinct_words:
    filt = df.str.findall(word)
    vocabulary[word] = df.loc[filt].index
```

However i get this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Can someone help me with this problem? I have tried a nested loop but since my original file is large it takes minutes, but the problem needs to be computed under 40 secs. I was told using re module would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Series.str.findall()` returns matched value as list. You can use `Series.str.contains()` to find if column contains value.

```py
for word in distinct_words:
    vocabulary[word] = df[df['Text'].str.contains(word)].index.tolist()
```

Comment: This gives the correct output. However since my data is large, it takes about 2 minutes to make the vocabulary. I was wondering if there is another faster way of doing this with larger data?

Comment: @user8591488 Couldn't work out another way. But would you consider multi processing? Each process to handle one word in distinct_words.